# In Karate do we have any syntax to pass the values as run-time argument

Tags: karate

If i hit the 3rd api call, we are getting the otp in mobile. we need to provide that "**otp as a run time argument /any text box window to popup for OTP**" in a feature file of karate to hit 4th api call request.

Any in-built functionality available in karate or shall i make a move to java script on this.

Thanks much in advance for your response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No built in functionality. If the OTP is a web-page submit (HTTP POST) then you *might* be able to do that in Karate. Refer to the OAuth example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature

Yes you should probably take the help of someone who knows HTML / JS depending on what your situation is.

Comment: Yes, it is (POST Method) in our API. Do we have any option to pop-up the input box for entering the OTP value while executing it.

Comment: @PreethiRavi interesting. you know what, maybe you can write a simple Java main method that pops up a Swing or JavaFX Dialog and achieve what you want !